# Spring 4 Java based config with HTML

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to dispatch to html (instead of jsp) from a java based Spring 4 configured project.

This is the ApplicationContextConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("net.codejava.spring")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ApplicationContextConfig {
    @Bean(name = "viewResolver")
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/html/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return viewResolver;
    }
```

This is the SpringWebAppInitializer

```
public class SpringWebAppInitializer extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        appContext.register(ApplicationContextConfig.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("SpringDispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(appContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");

    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/css/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("/images/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/js/");
    }

}
```

This the webapp folder:

[image]

And this is the Spring controller:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

@RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView showLogin(){
        return new ModelAndView("login");
    }
}
```

But I'm getting this warn:

No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/spring/html/login.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'SpringDispatcher'

And the html don't shows.

Answer (score -1):

where is your html file located ?

place your html file like WEB-INF/views/login.html

use mapping

```
viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
viewResolver.setSuffix(".html");
```